# Error in pom file with no message or indication what's wrong

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, pom.xml

I am getting a weird error in my pom.xml file. When I click or hover on it, it doesn't say anything or highlights any error or issue. My projects haven't been working properly and I think this could be the reason.

The image below shows the error, bear in mind that this is just after I created the project. I have all the correct dependencies etc. The dependencies I am using are:

spring actuator,
spring boot 2.2.6,
spring web,
spring data jpa,
mysql drive

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Q2.1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Q2.1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

the image below shows the error

[image: the image below shows the error]

the image below shows the problem console on eclipse
[image: below is the problem console]

Comment: I can't see an error in that XML document. Are you sure you posted the right thing?

Comment: Whenever you have a need to post textual information, please post it as text. Text posted as images prevents readers from copying and pasting, which they might want to do to help you debug. When you edit this question, if it is indeed an XML document you wish to show, please supply it as text. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will upload now.

Comment: Lovely. Make sure you change the text "the image below shows the error", because it is no longer an image, and it doesn't show an error.

Comment: Think that's it now, thanks!!!!

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the problems window in eclipse? This would detail the specific issue you are having.

Comment: Aha, do you mean XML validity? That is not clear from your text. I have just spotted the tiniest error indicator in the margin of your image, which is not what I expected - I though you meant this file was an XML wrapper for a human-readable error message. Would you (a) edit your question again to make this crystal clear, and (b) run your XML through a validator to see what it says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is incompatibilities between the version of M2E and the version 3.1.2 of the maven-jar-plugin.

Until the problem is solved by the development teams of M2E or maven-jar-plugins, you have to add in your pom.xml file the following line in order to solve this issue:

```
</project>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

So your pom after the fix:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Q2.1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Q2.1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

Reference: https://github.com/sarl/sarl/issues/921